# Подскажите пожалуйста библиотеку для чтения и запись в оперативную память на Python

Tags: python, c++, linux

Если какая нибудь библиотека на Python что бы можно было прочитать значение по адрессу в памяти и записать туда новое значение ? Просто работал с C++ на windows там это встроенные функции, не нашёл решения как читать память с помощью C++ на linux. Какие есть решения для чтения оперативной памяти по адрессу с помощью C++ или Python на linux

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250625/access-memory-address-in-python

Comment: А вам зачем? . .

Comment: Если python, то для чего метка с++, если все равно, то зачем вообще вопрос, если в с++ можно спокойно читать и записывать?

Answer (score 0):

> прочитать значение по адрессу в памяти и записать туда новое значение

Сдаётся мне, что Вы не очень хорошо понимаете, о чём говорите. Самый первый вопрос - а **какой адрес** вы имеете в виду?

- Физический
- Логический
- Виртуальный

Если речь идёт о первых двух типах, то ответ прост - никак. Если же Вы говорите о третьем типе адреса, из userspace, то тут всё просто. Я предполагаю, что Вы хотите просто распаковать и потом упаковать некую структуру данных в памяти.  Для это есть Python модуль *struct*:

```
struct.pack(fmt, v1, v2, ...)
```

Упаковывает значения *v1, v2* и так далее, в строку байтов, в соответствии со строкой формата *fmt*.

```
struct.unpack(fmt, string)
```

Распаковывает содержимое строки байтов *string* в соответствии со строкой формата fmt. Возвращает кортеж распакованных значений. Длина строки *string* должна точно соответствовать размеру формата, который определяется функцией *calcsize()*.